# Retrieving Power Form URL with API

Tags: docusignapi

Currently I'm using a template, creating an Envelope from that template and uploading documents and sending with the Sender View all through the API. What I would like to do is use a power form that when I hit send I can somehow retrieve that url with the API and save it to my DB. How can I get that signing URL with the API ?

Answer (score 1):

That is currently not available through the API, you must use the web UI to perform this action at this time.

This may change at a later date, however I do not have any information on when that may be.

Your best option on getting it in the API is contacting your DocuSign Account Manager to submit an Enhancement Request (DocuSign Customer Support can also help you submit that as well).

Comment: So I'm creating an envelope from a template... then calling the sender view to upload documents. Once I've tagged the documents for the different roles in the template workflow, I hit send and don't want it to send emails rather save the links that are being sent in our DB to retrieve for signings. Is the Sender View the correct thing to be using. Would it be better to Upload the documents from my Portal rather than using the Sender View for uploading documents and sending the Envelope ? Then when we're ready for them to sign, call the Signing View with the Envelope ID ?

Comment: If that's the case how would I tag the documents ?